# Using jQuery Plugins alongside Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I know that ideally jQuery plugins should be repackaged into directives, but i'm not sure how I feel about that approach. Firstly it means, whenever the plugin is updated it's not just a matter of pulling a new repo, but also editing the directive.

How could I keep angular moduls separate from jquery plugins perhaps communicating to the jquery plugin via its api. Would requirejs or a similar library be appropriate for this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the plugins maintain their api, your directive should continue to work as desired. Directives over jQuery plugins are really just a wrapper adopting the `Angular Way`.

As most jQuery plugins are initiated with a single function call to a particular dom selection (usually passing in an options object), the directive boilerplate you use is extremely common.

By adopting the angular way, what you are doing is abstracting the jQuery plugin functionality to allow for a more modular and declarative html. Other than passing in any scope values to control plugin updating (which you would do anyway if it was a native directive), a basic directive would be as follows:

```
angular.directive('jqWrapper', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            $timeout(function(){
                elem.myJQueryFunction();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Obviously options, and watches can complicate it a little when needed, but the directive above would likely work with many jQuery plugins. Also note the use of `$timeout` to ensure the plugin is applied post rendering.

So basically don't think of a directive as something that is required to make jQuery plugins work. Think of a directive as extra functionality that converts your required jQuery code into something more modular and useful.